# WCF Web Config with Multiple SVC

Tags: c#, wcf

IIf I have multiple WCF services set up in a project like so:

```
ServiceA.svc
IServiceA.cs
ServiceB.svc
IServiceB.cs
```

And my web config has the following:

```
<services>
  <service name="Services.ServiceA">
    <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="Services.IServiceA" />
    <endpoint address="upload" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ImageUploadServiceBinding"
      name="" bindingName="ImageUploadServiceBinding" contract="Services.IServiceB" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Is that wrong? I ask because I have seen multiple ways of setting up WCF services when you have 'multiple' services and everyone seems to do it a different way. If I have multiple svc files in my project (multiple services), is it OK to group them into one "service" in the web.config and then separate them via endpoints like I have done above?

This will be hosted in IIS, btw.

Comment: It should be okay to do that. Can you give more information on why you want to do it that way? If you have different services, you should host different services. If is basically one service, you do not need different svc definitions. The basic idea of an service is that requests get to the point where they can be handled. So having different services in one virtual directory is maybe possible, but it seems contradictory of what an architecture of different services is about, which is separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why this would be a problem technically. WCF is built for this. You should keep in mind the deployment issues you could face.

Now, since it is one service, you can't just replace service A without replacing service B. This is okay if there are tightly coupled and share the exact same dependencies. If not, split them for maintainability.

Comment: Also, is it normal to not be able to navigate directly to the endpoints using a browser? If I try to go to ServiceA.svc/upload I get an error 400.

Comment: Any more on the error? Did you have the service meta data settings defined?

Comment: This is not normal. If you use the right address as specified in web.config / virtual directory you can and should navigate to the site. If you search for the full error without your class / sitenames, you should get immediate help to that kind of issues. Maybe some registation is missing or something like that.

Comment: @Mare: But you can't just navigate to the method, can you? The svc will work, but the method needs to be a GET in the first place to work.

Comment: Not to some method, but you can get a site and download a WSDL from it which gives you all endpoints and so on. IIS tells you "You have sucessfully created a site".

Comment: @Mare: but he is navigating to the method. My bad: binding address. Shouldn't work either.

Comment: The address in the browser should be something like http://localhost/SomeService.svc